# how to change a button color if all the required fields are filled

Tags: vue.js

Here I have written code in vue.js. And I have validated the fields. And here I have to change the button color when all the input fields are filled completely. And also if any fields are missed to fill and user tries to submit the form then the unfilled field should highlight with red color border. Thank you in advance please help me.

```html
<div id="app">
  <p>
    <label for='terms'>
      <input id='category' type='checkbox' v-model='category'/>
      <input id="title" type='text' v-model='title'/>
      <input id="address" type='text' v-model='address'>       
      <input id="city" type='text' v-model='city'/>
      <input id="state" type='text' v-model='state'/>
      <input id="zip" type='text' v-model='zip'/>
      <input id="price" type='text' v-model='price'/>
      <input id="Description" type='text' v-model='Description'/>
    </label>
    
  </p>
```

**vue.js**

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#q-vikreya',

    components: {
        "vue-form-g": VueFormGenerator.component
    },

    data() {
            return {
            step:1,
            category:'',
            title:'',
            address:'',
            city:'',
            state:'',
            zip:'',
            price:'',
            description:'',
    methods: {
    checkForm: function (e) {
      if (this.category && this.title && this.address && this.city && this.state && this.price && this.description) {
        return true;
      }

      this.errors = [];

      if (!this.category) {
        this.errors.push('Name required.');
      }
      if (!this.title) {
        this.errors.push('Age required.');
      }
      if (!this.address) {
        this.errors.push('Age required.');
      }
      if (!this.city) {
        this.errors.push('Age required.');
      }
      if (!this.state) {
        this.errors.push('Age required.');
      }
      if (!this.price) {
        this.errors.push('Age required.');
      }
      if (!this.description) {
        this.errors.push('Age required.');
      }
      if (!this.description) {
        this.errors.push('Age required.');
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    },
      submitForm: function(){
            axios({
                method : "POST",
                url: "{% url 'PostAd' %}", //django path name
                headers: {'X-CSRFTOKEN': '{{ csrf_token }}', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                data : {"category":this.category, "title":this.title,
                "address":this.address,
                "city": this.city,
                "state": this.state,
                "zip": this.zip,
                "price": this.price,
                "description": this.description,
                "radio_price": this.radio_price,
                "Job_title": this.model,
                },//data
              }).then(response => {
              console.log("response");
              console.log(response.data);
                  this.success_msg = response.data['msg'];
                 window.location.replace('{% url "classifieds" %}')  // Replace home by the name of your home view

              }).catch(err => {
                     this.err_msg = err.response.data['err'];
              console.log("response1");
              console.log(err.response.data);

              });

          },

  },

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need js or vue to achieve it. You can utilize [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute and [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) pseudo class to control the styling.

```css
input {
  outline: none;
  border: solid 1px green;
}

input:invalid {
  border: solid 1px red;
}

input:invalid ~ button {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label>Name: </label><input required="required" value="Alice" />
<br />
<label>Age: </label><input required="required" />
<br />
<label>Address: </label><input required="required" />
<br />
<button>Submit</button>
```